# How do I forward requests to another URL without actually changing the URL in Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, rewrite

I have Apache running in a domain, for example `http://example.com`. I also have Tomcat running on my server and I've forwarded all requests made to `http://example.com/t/` to Tomcat and all other URLs are served by Apache directly.

My problem is I have a URL like `http://example.com/bar`, but it should actually point to `http://example.com/t/bar`.

In other words, the URL should be processed by Tomcat which gets the application context "bar".

Problem is, I'm not quite sure how to make the proper rewrite rule for this. I tried adding this to sites-available/default

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bar(.*) /t/bar$1 [R]
```

But that doesn't preserve the URL, and instead just redirects to the Tomcat URL with the `/t/` prefix. If I remove the `[R]`, then I just get a 404.

What is the proper `RewriteRule` to solve my problem?

Comment: You'd probably get better answers on serverfault.com

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say "but it should actually point to http://example.com/t/bar" and then you say "But that doesn't preserve the URL, and instead just redirects to the Tomcat URL with the /t/ prefix." Do you want the change the URL or not?

Comment: Manni, sorry for the confusion. No, I do not want the URL to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the 'P' (proxy) option on the mod_rewrite rule to be done internally to the server. You will also need to enable [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

from the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> 'proxy|P' (force proxy)
>
> This flag
>   forces the substitution part to be
>   internally sent as a proxy request and
>   immediately (rewrite processing stops
>   here) put through the proxy module.
>   You must make sure that the
>   substitution string is a valid URI
>   (typically starting with
>   http://hostname) which can be handled
>   by the Apache proxy module. If not,
>   you will get an error from the proxy
>   module. Use this flag to achieve a
>   more powerful implementation of the
>   ProxyPass directive, to map remote
>   content into the namespace of the
>   local server.
>
> **Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in**
>   **order to use this flag.**